# Dynamic queries in Spring Boot Cosmos DB implementation

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am developing an application using Azure Cosmos DB for Spring.

I have a structure with model classes and a ReactiveCosmosRepository, which I use to do queries.

I normally annotate my queries in my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface ArchivedDocumentRepository extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<ArchivedDocument, String> {

@Query("SELECT * FROM c)
Flux<ArchivedDocument> findAllArchivedDocuments();
    
@Query("SELECT * FROM c where c.document_id = @documentId")
Mono<ArchivedDocument> findArchivedDocument(@Param("documentId") String documentId);
    
}
```

But now I need to create the SQL using some logic, and cannot annotate it like this.
How can I do this?

I have also used the Azure Cosmos SDK directly, where you do like this:

```
client = new CosmosClientBuilder().endpoint("SOMEURL")
        .key("SOMEKEY")
        .preferredRegions(Collections.singletonList("SOMELOCATION"))
        .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.EVENTUAL).buildClient();

database = client.getDatabase("DBNAME");
String containerName = "CONTAINERNAME";
CosmosContainer container = database.getContainer(containerName);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM c";

CosmosPagedIterable<DocumentMetadata> filteredDocumentMetadata = container.queryItems(sql, new CosmosQueryRequestOptions(), DocumentMetadata.class);

...
}
```

If I combine my existing repository code with similar code to this in my service, I can retrieve the data I like and build queries how I like, but it seems a bit unnecessary to e.g. instantiate "client" object, when I already have a connection?

Any advices? How can I combine both the SDK directly with the Spring layer to be able to create queries based on logic instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on right path. You probably need to work on lower level using `CosmosAsyncClient`

If you are using configuration which `extends AbstractCosmosConfiguration` then you dont even need to create `CosmosAsyncClient` since its defined in AbstractCosmosConfiguration class.

The custom repository

```
package com.vob.reactive.webflux.service;

import com.azure.cosmos.CosmosAsyncClient;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.SqlParameter;
import com.azure.cosmos.models.SqlQuerySpec;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomRepository {


    private final CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient;

    @Autowired
    public CustomRepository(CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient) {
        this.cosmosAsyncClient = cosmosAsyncClient;
    }

    public <T> Mono<T> getSomethingFrom(String database, String container, String id, Class<T> classType){
        return this.cosmosAsyncClient
                .getDatabase(database)
                .getContainer(container)
                .queryItems(new SqlQuerySpec("select * from c where c.document_id = @documentId", new SqlParameter("documentId", id)), classType)
                .single();
    }

}
```

You would probably need to improve getDatabase and getContainer by storing them in Map so you dont need to check if they exists each time

Comment: But this approach also creates a new client? I already "have a client" created by the Spring Cosmos lib , so could I not reuse that somehow? In this case I will have two...

Comment: You can let me tune it

Comment: You right if you use cosmosdb config you dont even need to define AsyncClient bean its done in base class.

Comment: The structure worked fine! Was able to query database. But there was some error with how you sent parameter. It did not like @documentId in the query for some reason. But I can investigate that.

Comment: One more thing: You write "You would probably need to improve getDatabase and getContainer by storing them in Map so you dont need to check if they exists each time". Is there a resource/time penalty by calling getDatabase().getContainer()? The reference says that is gets the instances without doing a service call. Is it an issue to do these calls each time a query is sent?

Comment: @Ziggy000 I am not sure,  if you create databases and containers from terraform or arm template then maybe I wouldn't worry much. What i meant is when you create from code using createIfNotExists then defenitely I would use map.